# GCPW Azure Cloud Windows

Tags: windows, google-chrome, google-cloud-platform, windows-10, google-workspace

I have installed Google Credential Provider on an Azure Windows 10. However, when I reboot the machine there is no option to sign in with Google. Do I have to do something differently in case of cloud Machines? Cannot figure this out, please help.

With the GCPW installer package(.msi) I get an error "There is a problem with the package" and it doesn't install. The GCPW package from my google admin(.exe) installs but still there is no option to sign-in with Google on the login screen.

Comment: Your question has no details on what you configured.

Comment: @JohnHanley Once I install GCPW and reboot on a physical laptop/PC , there is an option to sign-in with Google to Windows. That is all I need. All the Configuration, I have done in Google Admin. The same is not working on the cloud machine. So, there is no configuration needed to be able to see the "Add your Work Account" or Google sign-in option.